# direct FTP link with asterisk

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I have troubles with special characters in ftp direct link as follows:

```
<img src="ftp://martin:cardinal@mysite.sk/data/voucher.jpg"> // working

<img src="ftp://martin:cardinal*@mysite.sk/data/voucher.jpg"> // not working
```

If I change password from `cardinal` to `cardinal*` and change the ftp link, then browser no longer loads an image. How can I create direct FTP link with asterisk in password?

**I know  direct ftp link with credidentals is not secure, but please avoid of any offtopic.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an *asterix* in url is not a good idea. But if you really have to, use the **HEX** value of it (*2A*) with the escape character `%` like this:

```
<img src="ftp://martin:cardinal%2a@mysite.sk/data/voucher.jpg">
```